# Cannot query number in between two negative numbers

Tags: python, sqlite, web2py

I try to query for numbers within a range, but I keep getting empty result if both numbers are < 0:

```
max = float(request.vars.max) #-87
min = float(request.vars.min) #-90
qry1 = (max > db.db1.nbr)
qry2 = (min < db.db1.nbr)
results = db(qry1 & qry2).select(db.db1.ALL)   # returns no result
```

If I switch the URL query so `max=-90` and `min=-87`, I get the results I need, but this doesn't make sense. Can anyone explain why the query behaves this way?

Comment: What are the types of `db.db1` and `db.db1.nbr`?

Comment: @goncalopp , the declaration is like the following db.define_table('db1',
   Field('nbr', 'double', notnull=True),
     :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a test program and the code works. It must have been a migration issue because I didn't specify the type of the nbr field the first time (and it defaulted to string).